# View Logs - HP Router

Tags: router, hp, 3com

I have a HP MSR30-10 A router at the edge of our network. The rest of our switches are HP, but it turns out the the HP router comes from the old 3Com world and speaks a different language from the switches. Dang!

I'd like to view the logs for my HP router. On the HP switch, I'd do a:

```
show log -r
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work on the HP router. I'm reviewing the manuals, but haven't found any simple (or as simple) way to do this. I see I can dump the logs to a file, but can't seem to get the file off the router. We are currently not using the web interface, just the serial console.

The question: How can I view the recent logs from my HP router while plugged into the serial console?

Thanks for any help you can give! I'd be happy to provide more details.

Comment: Can the router be configured to log to an external syslog server?

Comment: It can, but we currently aren't using one. I might plan on one in the future though if there isn't a way to view the logs directly on the device.

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon. According to the manual, it can output logs in either UniCom or HP log format. The manual doesn't mention anything of syslog. These might just be internal names though.

Comment: Hmm... well, for now I've enabled the web interface that has log searching capabilities. Not what I was hoping for, but still a good start for now.